# 404 page redirect issue?

Tags: 7, redirection, .htaccess

I am using drupal7 404 page redirect to my custom page using htaccess.

Ex : `www.drupal7.com/est` link redirect to my custom page. But `www.drupal7.com/solution/est` link redirect to `www.drupal7.com/solution` page.

How to fix this redirect issue?

Comment: May you rephrase your question? I can't understand what you've actually done. Are you using the 404 page settings on admin/config/system/site-information?